# Autosuggest from Here Maps API without country information

Tags: here-api, autosuggest

I'm implementing a search on my server using the service https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest. However, I need information from the country of the place. If I use the **lookup** service to detail the place, performance drops a lot. Would there be a way to return the country using autosuggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html).

As you can see in their example, the response contains suggestions with `address`property.